# What part of linux is responsible for loading themes?

Tags: linux, themes

Well, some time ago, i started building an LFS, and (for some reason) i started to think about some BLFS stuff, like "what icon theme will it use?" and "if possible, can I make my own theme loader?".

So, what part of a distro is responsible for loading themes (like, what packages)?

Can I make my own loader?

If yes, how can i do this?

What is supported and what isn't (for instance, animated SVGs, or icons to files with specific names)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "theme loader" is not a separate thing that would exist on Linux. Support for themes is literally part of the components that are *being themed* – for example, if you have an app that uses the GTK 3 library to draw its user interface (buttons, inputs, etc.) then it is GTK 3 itself that looks at the `gtk-theme-name` setting, loads a specific appearance.

Similarly, GTK+ 2 loads its own skins/styles, Qt loads its own, EFL loads its own, and each of them uses a different theme format. The same applies to icon themes, because programs written in GTK will typically use the "load an icon" functions that are part of GTK's API – so it's still each toolkit's job to look in the correct icon theme directory (usually /usr/share/icons/Foo) and load the correct file.

The different toolkits do mostly agree on the **icon** theme format – *mostly* – so if you put an icon theme at the standard location, both GTK and Qt will use it when you configure the "icon theme name". The expected formats are PNG for predefined sizes and SVG for 'scalable' icons.

Comment: Thank you, your answer made clear some questions i was struggling with, now i'll see how their api work so that i can play with them a little bit